# excel 2010 Blank cell in place of 0

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

How do I use this formula and add if 0,"" so the cells are blank rather than 0 
=SUMIF(NotReady!AA17:AA50,5,NotReady!AB17:AB50)

I would like it in formula rather then cell format please

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Let's call your formula `x`

```
x => "=SUMIF(NotReady!AA17:AA50,5,NotReady!AB17:AB50)"
```

If x = 0 then return "", otherwise display value. The formula for this would be

```
=if(x=0,"",x)
```

So, replace the above x's in the formula with your formula to get

```
=If(SUMIF(NotReady!AA17:AA50,5,NotReady!AB17:AB50)=0,"",SUMIF(NotReady!AA17:AA50,5,NotReady!AB17:AB50))
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved by a simple formula:

```
=TEXT(SUMIF(NotReady!AA17:AA50,5,NotReady!AB17:AB50),"#")
```